# Azurite docker image and CORS

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-explorer, azurite

I'm developing an Azure function application in C#. I'm trying to run the application locally and am having a large amount of difficulty around getting a file upload to work with Azurite.

The application has a frontend written in Angular. It utilizes the `"@azure/storage-blob": "^12.6.0"` library to upload a file to Azure storage with the following code:

```js
      private uploadFile(audioMedia: AudioMediaDto, file: File | null, storageAccessInformation: StorageAccessInformationDto): Observable<TransferProgressEvent> {
        const sub = new Subject<TransferProgressEvent>();
        if (file) {
          const url = `${env.blobStorageUri}?${storageAccessInformation.accessToken}`;
          const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(url);
          const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(storageAccessInformation.containerName);
          containerClient.getBlobClient(`${storageAccessInformation.uploadDirectory}/${audioMedia.id}`)
                         .getBlockBlobClient()
                         .uploadData(
                           file,
                           {
                             onProgress: (progress: TransferProgressEvent) => sub.next(progress)
                           }
                         )
                         .then(
                           () => sub.complete(),
                           () => sub.error('')
                         );
        } else {
          sub.error('');
        }
    
        return sub.asObservable();
      }
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
    version: "3.9"
    services:
      azurite:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
        command: "azurite --loose --blobHost 0.0.0.0 --blobPort 10000 --queueHost 0.0.0.0 --queuePort 10001 --location /workspace --debug /workspace/debug.log"
        ports:
          - 10010:10000
          - 10011:10001
          - 10012:10002
        volumes:
          - ./azurite:/workspace
    
      frontend:
        build: frontend
        ports:
          - 4200:4200
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, I open the Azure storage emulator and connect to my Azurite instance and then right click on the 'Blob Containers' and configure a CORS policy that looks as follows:

- Allowed Origins: http://localhost:4200
- Allowed Methods: PUT,OPTIONS
- Allowed Headers: content-type,x-ms-blob-type,x-ms-client-request-id,x-ms-version

I create a container through Azure storage explorer and then right click on it and choose "Get Shared Access Signature...". I make the Expiry Time for a year in the future and select all of the permissions. When I click create though, I see the following error message:

> Error when calling Azure Storage:'version' must be >= '2019-10-10'
> when providing 'x' permission.

While I believe this will be a problem, if I currently run the application as is and try to upload a document to the container, I'm getting the following message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:10010/devstoreaccount1/container-name/src%2F0e237853-f7a9-4dc8-b892-a0eddc2688d8?sv=2018-03-28&st=2021-06-30T15%3A03%3A48Z&se=2022-07-01T15%3A03%3A00Z&sr=c&sp=c&sig=qWHZ4wpkoVZwvJbPK0r6%2Fwf%2B5LL3kBjgEc6oFm3ikUA%3D'
> from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I can see that the CORS settings I applied to my container were saved though because when I look at the `./azurite/__azurite_db_blob__.json` file, I see the following section in it:
[image]

What setup/steps am I missing, that would enable me to upload a document to the azurite container running in the docker image?

Comment: Can you try by changing both the `Allowed Headers` and `Exposed Headers` to `*`? In my experience different browsers send and receive different sets of headers.

Comment: That seemed to fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CORS, the values specified in `AllowedHeaders` and `ExposedHeaders` properties must match exactly with the headers sent and received respectively. A mismatch in these header values will cause CORS related errors.

Furthermore, in my experience different browsers send/receive different headers and that would also cause CORS related errors.

Simplest way to fix this is to set `*` for both `AllowedHeaders` and `ExposedHeaders` properties. What this will do is allow all headers and you will not get CORS error.