# Unable to set Azurite CORS rules using its CLI

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azurite

Please note that this is not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70750222/azurite-docker-image-and-cors).

What is the exact Azurite CLI command to issue to set its CORS rules similar to the following screenshot in a docker compose file?

Example:

```yaml
  storageemulator:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite:latest"
    command: "azurite --loose"  # This command does not solve the CORS problem I am having.
    container_name: myemulator
```

[image]